# How to Get Image's Object Outline (Outer Boundary) in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

I'm working on image segmentation using Python and OpenCV right now.
I have a binary image which contains only one object (already thresholded using Otsu's Methods). I want to know how to get the image's object outline (outer boundary). So, there will be only a black image with a white object outline. Already tried Googling but still don't have idea.

I prefer to know how to do it manually without the built in function.

Answer (score 3):

**Built in function**: [findContours()](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours).

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.zeros((100,100), np.uint8)
a[10:20,30:40] = 1

im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(a, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cim = np.zeros_like(a)
cv2.drawContours(cim, contours, -1, 255, 1)
plt.matshow(cim, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
```

[image: findContours()]
**Manual approach**: An easy way would be subtracting an [eroded image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_morphology#Erosion) from the original image using [binary_erosion()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_erosion.html#scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_erosion).
 That will not necesarily result in a closed contour, depending on the geometry.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.ndimage.morphology import binary_erosion

a = np.zeros((100,100), np.uint8)
a[10:20,30:40] = 1
m = a - binary_erosion(a)
plt.matshow(m, cmap=plt.cm.gray)
```

[image: binary_erosion and subtraction]